# np.where issue above a certain value (#Numpy)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, performance

I'm facing to 2 issues in the following snippet using *np.where* (looking for indexes where A[:,0] is identical to B)

1. Numpy error when n is above a certain value (see error)
2. quite slow

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

So I'm wondering what I'm missing and/or misunderstanding, how to fix it, and how to speed-up the code. This is a basic example I've made to mimic my code, but in fact I'm dealing with arrays having (dozens of) millions of rows.

Thanks for your support

Paul

```
import numpy as np
import time

n=100_000  # with n=10 000 ok but quit slow
m=2_000_000



#matrix A
# A=np.random.random ((n, 4))
A = np.arange(1, 4*n+1, dtype=np.uint64).reshape((n, 4), order='F')

#Matrix B
B=np.random.randint(1, m+1, size=(m), dtype=np.uint64)
B=np.unique(B) # duplicate values are generally generated, so the real size remains lower than n

# use of np.where
t0=time.time()
ind=np.where(A[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) == B)
# ind2=np.where(B == A[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1))
t1=time.time()
print(f"duration={t1-t0}")
```

Comment: Could you describe what the actual end goal of this is?

Comment: goal ... basically to find the location of elements A into B (B necessarily greater than A) - all data are unsigned integers. From rows locations, I can perform addition tasks. Off course speed is a keyword and I'm using a often as possible vectorization

Comment: `len(B)` usually turns out to be around 1_264_000 (+- 500). `dtype('bool')` [takes 1 byte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602155/14627505). So with your current parameters, `(A[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) == B)` takes around 31_600_000_000 bytes (31.6 GB). You can check it by yourself with `(A[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) == B).nbytes`. If you want to add another 0 to your `n`, this will become 316 GB. Do you still want to use this, or you would rather describe your more general problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: humm ... ok for the feedback, especially for the test you provided. I ever been confront to memory issues, but I was not thinking about it from the warning. As previously said, I'm focussing to find location of common values of A[:, 0] into B: to extract data complete rows, or to remove them for example. I guess I can imagine different tests: 1) making loops using one row at a time (with the help of Numba to speed-up the process 2) to parse A into smaller 1D array to reduce the number of loops. Other suggestions? Paul

Comment: What input for `A` do you **really** have? In your code you have a line commented out.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that we use only the first column of `A`? All its other values are irrelevant? Maybe you should then declare `A` only to have the values that we use - to be more clear

Comment: Why are you saying “B necessarily greater than A”? B can equal A in some positions

Comment: Do you need both row and column of the matching numbers? Or only rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, `A[:, 0]` is just

```
np.arange(n/4, dtype=np.uint64)
```

And if you are interested only in row indexes where `A[:, 0]` is in `B`, then you can get them like this:

```py
row_indices = np.where(np.isin(first_col_of_A, B))[0]
```

- If you then want to select the rows of A with these indices, you don't even have to convert the boolean mask to index locations. You can just select the rows with the boolean mask: `A[np.isin(first_col_of_A, B)]`
- There are better ways to select random elements from an array. For example, you could use [`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) with `replace=False`. Also, [Numpy: Get random set of rows from 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14262654/14627505).
- I feel there is almost certainly a better way to do the whole thing that you are trying to do with these index locations.
  I recommend you study the [Numpy User Guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/index.html) and the [Pandas User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) to see what cool things are available there.

---

Honestly, with your current implementation you don't even need the first column of `A` at all, because row indicies simply equal the elements of `A[:, 0]`. Here:

```py
row_indices = B[B < n]
row_indices.sort()
print(row_indices)
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution and for links; let me having a look on what you've suggested. => yes I'm focusing on rows indexes of common values - Do not pay attention on what I've made prior the np.where, it has been made only to mimic my model (I didn't imagine it has been a memory issue, but maybe a type conversion issue and something else). Paul

Comment: It looks like you where trying to solve a simple problem in a very complicated way. Without more accurately described inputs there's not much more I can do.

Comment: I was not precise enough (my fault I guess), but I want to find common values between the first column in A and B, and to get their position in the array (row number); values do not follow each other; the new challenge will be to speed-up it by reducing the amont of memory. Paul

Comment: @Paul18fr Well, does my answer solve your problem? What do you mean by "values do not follow each other". I would like you to edit your question to show what values actually are there, and remove everything unnecessary

Comment: the simple 'row_indices = np.where(np.isin(first_col_of_A, B))[0]' runs 1200 times faster and do not need as much memory as my snippet ... so yes absolutly, thanks :-)